# Rails migration depends on settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have some migrations that depends on instance settings. If something is set some tables will join to one table, if not it will join to other table.

Of course when I run the migration locally it will generate a db/schema.rb that can be different from the one expected on a server with different settings.

Will that be an issue? Ie. for specs and deploys.

Comment: This is not a happy path for rails as it favors convention.  It can be done, but you will need to handle it in your specs and any other code sitting on top of the affected tables.

Comment: To further on what @dbugger writes this is just a straight up bad idea. Migrations are intentend to be one-time use transformations for your database schema. They should just transforms the database schema in the simplest way possible and the whole point is to acheive **parity** so that you have the exact same schema in development, testing  and production so that you don't ship bugs.

Comment: If you're writing migrations for a gem what you want to do instead is to write a code generator which generates migrations with the desired settings instead. That way you can generate the migration and you can know from just looking at the generated code exactly whats supposted to happen. Look at the Devise and Rolify gems if you want examples of how this can be done.

Comment: this needs to be handled in the code, not the migration